# Oracle Version requirements for ORA2PG tool to migrate from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, version, ora2pg

I am trying to figure out what is the minimum and maximum versions or Oracle supported by ORA2PG tool for migrating Oracle database to PostgreSQL.  I cannot locate it in their documentation.  If someone has a link to this guidance, I will appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used the tool, but - it seems that all it cares about is Oracle **Client** (or the **Server** itself) installed as ORA2PG needs "something" to use to establish connection to the database.

The lowest Oracle database version I found to be used with ORA2PG is **8i**, while the highest is **18c**. I presume that 19c would work as well as both 18c and 19c actually represent 12c releases (but Oracle decided to change the way it numbers the releases).

Therefore, I'd say that it covers all currently supported (by the Oracle corp.), as well as quite a few unsupported Oracle database versions.